# Build Opencv 3.1.0 with IPP ippicv_windows_20151201.zip

Tags: opencv, cmake, intel-ipp

I'm trying to build OpenCV 3.1.0 on a stand alone computer (there is no internet access).

I have an Intel composer 2015 installed, which include IPP v8.

During CMake build configuration, I get the following message:

```
Cmake error at 3rdparty/downloader.cmake.73

for file: [..... /ippicv_windows_20151201.zip]

expected hash [...] actual hash [...]
```

I figure out that I need to manually download ippicv_windows_20151201.zip and place it in the sources sub - folder.

Do you know where I can download it from?

I can exclude the build flag: "WITH_IPP" , In that case, I'd not build with IPP at all, which is something I don't want.

I'd rather like to build OpenCV with my pre-installed IPP (Intel Composer), not the downloaded free version from OpenCV, Do you know how I can do that ?

BWT, What is the difference between build WITH_IPP and WITH_IPP_A flags ?

P.S. I posted the same question on OpenCV forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have an Intel composer which includes IPP library.

Go to your Opencv CMake --> Add entry (right side) --> Insert variable as a path:

```
IPP_ROOT
```

Set with the library location

Thus, would compile Opencv with IPP  library from the Intel Composer

IPP_A comes for asynchronous IPP which is currently experimental

Answer (score 1):

If the downloader.cmake is not finding the hash perhaps is not available yet or there is some error when reaching the URL (downloading protocol maybe?). Download the previous version from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/3rdparty/ippicv/), it'll do the work. Just need to place it in the correct folder. I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 with the 20141027 with no problem at all.